# DataTable columns inside columns or merged row table structure

Tags: c#, datatable

I've had a Google but I find no answer. You know how say in MS Word, when you insert a table, you can merge the columns of one single row to create a column-less row? Or have say a main header and then more columns inside it? Like so:

Merged Row:

|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|

|Value|Value|Value|

|Merged Row|

|Value|Value|Value|

God the text formatting is awful on this web-site...and the Header Column example:

|Main Header||Another Main Header|

|Column 1|Column2||Column1|Column2|

I'm trying to achieve this in a written DataTable in C# which is being populated by an array. But I'm interested in changing its structure as one of the above, whichever is possible/easier.

So I've created my DataTable and added normal columns and rows etc. But I'd like to create either a merged row or a main header to display. Instead of having a repeated value in a single column for the values I am getting.

Can someone please provide a quick example on how I could achieve either one of those? Because repeated value will just look ugly.

Cheers.

Comment: When you say "I've created my DataTable", are you talking about a DataGrid / DataGridView? Coloumn/Row Definitions? or is this a VBA question and you're literally talking about programmatically creating a table in a Word document?

Comment: No, In c# (as tag suggests) there's a DataTable type in System.Data namespace. I've created one of those based on my array. I have added columns and rows to it. However, what I can see is that you can only assign row values to a particular column. How can I still make a row being part of the table but having no columns? Is it even possible? If not, I'd like to know that may be that single value that I'd like to display can be displayed as a column above all other columns? Again, is that possible? How? Thanks

Comment: You're talking about displaying data in a particular way but a `DataTable` has nothing to do with display.  It is for storage and that's that.  How you display the data is up to you.  The same data can be displayed in innumerable different ways.  In a WinForms app, one of the most common ways to display the contents of a `DataTable` is with a `DataGridView`.  You can choose which columns to display and merge cells in that grid if desired.  In short, you're looking in the wrong place to do what you want to do.  It is a presentation issue, not a data issue.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know you could do that. Because I thought that you make up the structure in the way you store it and then GridView once bound - will just output whatever's stored. Can you please write this up as an answer to my question, so I can set it to solved. Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're talking about displaying data in a particular way but a
>   DataTable has nothing to do with display. It is for storage and that's
>   that. How you display the data is up to you. The same data can be
>   displayed in innumerable different ways. In a WinForms app, one of the
>   most common ways to display the contents of a DataTable is with a
>   DataGridView. You can choose which columns to display and merge cells
>   in that grid if desired. In short, you're looking in the wrong place
>   to do what you want to do. It is a presentation issue, not a data
>   issue. –

jmcilhinney